# Use HDD enclosure as portable hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

Someone here suggested that i should use an external hdd enclosure since my pc doesnt support a 2nd hdd and i want to use my old hdd. I will be permanently plugging that hdd enclosure to my pc and someone said it isnt safe. I'm really concerned since i would be using that drive and i'll probably be always using it since i'd play the music files i have in there. 
Also, would it be ok if i use that enclosure as a portable external drive?

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

nonsense. it's not unsafe. See if it works. But at worst it just won't get enough power if it is getting its power from a single USB port(and will work when you give it enough power). So it should be either external power or some use 2 USB ports. You can get an adaptor to adapt SATA->USB takes a SATA laptop hdd and gives 2 USB ports. Or you can get one for a desktop sized hard drive that probably uses more power and needs an external ACDC adaptor.

I have a portable USB SATA drive that runs on one USB cable, so it is possible, though(for some reason)it works in one comp and not another and I prefer adaptors as I can then use an internal drive. An enclosure is just a box with an adaptor in it.   Note- A single USB3 port can output more power than two USB2 ports so adaptors for USB3 would use one USB port rather than two.

Comment: There can be problems with the temperature. Some enclosures don't offer any cooling and the drives can get hot (around 50℃) if they're used a bit more.

Comment: Is there an enclosure without an ac adapter? I just want it to have usb since I don't have space anymore for more ac plug. I'm just planning now to buy those sata to usb bridge so I can just use those once in a while

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu yeah that's my problem. Considering that I will play the audio files from that hdd for long hours.

Comment: @jeffmangum  yeah I use one of these on a laptop sata drive http://www.gizfever.com/images/USB_SATA_Adapter2.jpg    of course, if you have space for an 8-10 port powered usb hub eg pluggable make one, or xenon do, then great. but you can plug that in 2 usb ports of your computer, if you have 2 free ports!

Comment: @jeffmangum By the way, you should realise your question title is absolutely insane. A HDD enclosure with a HDD in it is a portable HDD. Your question is almost as mad as asking if you can use a toothbrush to brush your teeth.

Comment: Its obvious that those connectors are for transferring reasons only right? Cause I can't just permanently plug the hdd using that. I guess I'm going with that cause the enclosure is a bit pricey and I'm afraid it will go to waste. I'm planning to buy that bridge thing

Comment: www.cdrking.com/?mod=products&type=view&sid=8819&main=140 I'm not sure if this thing works the same like the adapter though. The product description really isn't clear.

Comment: the adaptor I linked to in the pic(like any adaptor that works!) is for permanent too. As I said, an enclosure IS just that with a box around it. This is electronics remember, it's what these things look like when you remove the box. Look at what your computer looks like without a box

Comment: @jeffmangum  that cdrking one is different, I can't see how it powers the device. You need one with 2 USB ports.   Just look on ebay, and get something that looks just like the one I linked to.  Search for SATA to USB http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dual-USB-2-0-to-SATA-15-7-Pin-Data-and-Power-Cable-Adapter-For-2-5-inch-HDD-SSD-/251299405194?pt=US_Drive_Cables_dapters&hash=item3a829c9d8a     Ebay is not junk, people sell new stuff on there, there are lots of sellers with great reps.

Comment: And if you're worried about your data, just make sure you run programs to test the drive.  Doing that will also check the adaptor too. Because if all the tests run on the drive through the adaptor, then the adaptor is working fine. The Hard drive manufacturer website has such programs. WinDFT by Hitachi might run on other drives too. Your data is at more risk from a bad hard drive than from a bad adaptor.

Comment: @barlop i dont know cause i asked here that its unsafe just plugging the naked hdd and leaving the pcb exposed. Ebay has a lot of those but too bad i dont live in the us and shipping costs a lot. So the bridge adapter wont work? too bad cause its really cheap. the one you posted are overpriced here i dont get it.

Comment: @jeffmangum   You don't have to say, but what country are you in? there is an ebay.co.uk and probably an ebay for your country. And I doubt postage is more than 10 dollars.. it shouldn't be an arm and a leg to post something so light from the US,  via USPS. Using public transport or Driving a car is expensive. Posting a cable from the US is not. If I go out and buy a half decent pizza it might cost more.

Comment: @barlop Philippines. I dont want to spend too much on something that'll probably go to waste. I'll probably go with the bridge thing. it looks like it doesnt need power and is plug and play..

Comment: heh ok, you can jump off a cliff too you know! (though i'm not recommending it)